# Error While update column name with Liquibase xml

Tags: mysql, xml, liquibase

I am trying to update database column name with help of Liquibase xml on linux machine MYSQL.

My xml code for update column is

```
 <renameColumn tableName="AAA" oldColumnName="bbb_id" newColumnName="ccc_id" columnDataType="bigint" />
```

but this line is throw error like `ERROR [2017-11-16 15:42:28,247] liquibase: migrations.xml: migrations.xml::3.15.1::maulik.kakadiya: Change Set migrations.xml::3.15.1::maulik.kakadiya failed.  Error: Error on rename of './MY_DB/#sql-4bf_322' to './MY_DB/AAA' (errno: 150) [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE MY_DB.AAA CHANGE bbb_id ccc_id BIGINT]`

After getting this error I have tried with bellow simple sql query

```
<sql>ALTER TABLE `AAA` CHANGE COLUMN `bbb_id` `ccc_id` BIGINT(20);
    <comment>find onther why, beacuse rename query throw error</comment>
</sql>
```

Also "bbb_id" is a foreign-key reference.

But this statement is throwing same  error.

But if I have run Simple SQL query of this statement as per bellow query

```
ALTER TABLE `AAA` CHANGE COLUMN `bbb_id` `ccc_id` BIGINT(20);
```

Then this SQL query run successfully, but if I tried with Liquibase xml for same opration then this code is throwing error.

Any idea for this kind of problem?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it is happening, but I can suggest a troubleshooting step - instead of using the liquibase `update` command, try using the `updateSQL` command, which will generate the SQL that liquibase runs. Compare that to what you are doing manually and see if you can tell what the difference is.